# How to save a variable in AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, twitter4j

I am using Twitter 4j to post tweet on single button. If user revoke access of my app then its showing Error in Logcat in do in background i want this error and if this error comes my another hide button of twitter authorize app visible. how do i do that please help. I need that error and if its exists i want to hide show my buttons.

```
 class updateTwitterStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {

        String status = args[0];
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

            String access_token = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");

            String access_token_secret = mSharedPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");


            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            twitter4j.Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(status);

            File extStore = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/Twitter/Cache/demo.jpg");
            statusUpdate.setMedia(extStore);

            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.d("Failed to post!", e.getMessage());

            error=e; //error is exception
        }
        return null;}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       pDialog.dismiss();

       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Posted to Twitter!"+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    /* i need a variable like int a =10; access it globally, How i do that/*
       } } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the `exception` in a variable and check it in `onPostExecute`()
and hide your button ..

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
    Exception error;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
             // do work
             return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = e;

            return false;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Success!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
            if (error != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //error occurs hide button here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to declare my a sync class abstract is it OK? I can't make doInBackground(Void... params) as void , because i need string to update status!!!

Comment: this is a template ....you can use your class too just pass boolean in last parameter `String, String, Boolean`

Comment: your trick works thanks man , !! i am using tweet  in a custom list view using ViewHolder , how do i hide these button can i use flag here in if and else condition or it returns null? i am beginner.

Comment: you can use `holder.button_view.setVisibility(View.GONE); in `onpostExecute`

Comment: PlanetArrayAdapter.ViewHolder   viewHolder;
                    viewHolder = null;
                    viewHolder.twitter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: last request please can you explain better constructor to use to initialize View Holder ... please !!!

Comment: view holder is a part of your adapter `getView`..method..where it dynamically initialize the views

Comment: ok ., but i am using async outside the get View.. And View Holder Above  My Adapter Class. So how i call viewholder outside get view?

Comment: by this method  for (int i = 0; i < mainListView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        View vi = mainListView.getChildAt(i);

                        final PlanetArrayAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (PlanetArrayAdapter.ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

                    viewHolder.twitter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.twitter1.setVisibility(View.GONE); .... thnx for a help man